# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: legacyRetryPolicy cannot be null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, mocking

I am writing a junit test case to call an api deployed on aws api gateway.
The code is :

```
@Test
public void testAwsApiUtilsMakeRequest() throws Exception {
  RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy(PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_RETRY_CONDITION,
                                            PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_STRATEGY,
                                            3, true);

  ClientConfiguration cfg = Mockito.mock(ClientConfiguration.class);
  RetryPolicyAdapter rpa = new RetryPolicyAdapter(retryPolicy, cfg);

  System.out.println(rpa.getLegacyRetryPolicy());

  cfg.setRetryPolicy(rpa.getLegacyRetryPolicy());
  cfg.withMaxErrorRetry(3);

  Request request = Mockito.mock(Request.class);
  request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
  request.setEndpoint(new URI("http://localhost:" + port));
  request.setResourcePath("/myapro-1.0.0/profiles/" + "123");
  request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
  Response<AmazonWebServiceResponse<String>> awsResponse = Mockito.mock(Response.class);

  Mockito.when(awsApiUtils.postToAwsClient(request, cfg))
  .thenReturn(awsResponse);

  Mockito.when(awsApiUtils.makeRequest(request))
  .thenReturn(awsResponse.getAwsResponse().getResult());
  //assertThat(sdReprocessController.getProfileInfo("123"));

}
```

When I am running the test I am getting the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: legacyRetryPolicy cannot be null
Does anyone know how to resolve the issue / how to set legacyRetryPolicy? Thanks.

Here is the log:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: legacyRetryPolicy cannot be null

```
at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
at com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicyAdapter.<init>(RetryPolicyAdapter.java:36)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:347)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:320)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:308)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:286)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:269)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:253)
at org.act.leap.util.AwsApiUtils.postToAwsClient(AwsApiUtils.java:62)
at org.act.leap.resttemplate.controller.SdReprocessControllerTest.testAwsApiUtilsMakeRequest(SdReprocessControllerTest.java:251)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Comment: please share the full stack trace and Exception

Comment: I've added those.

Comment: @elbraulio ^^^^

Comment: I don't know how that library work, but be careful that `cfg.setRetryPolicy(rpa.getLegacyRetryPolicy());` is actually setting the property. If not mock it. Also I recommend to use `doReturn(awsResponse).when(awsApiUtils).postToAwsClient(any(), any());` instead of `Mockito.when(awsApiUtils.postToAwsClient(request, cfg))
  .thenReturn(awsResponse);` to avoid null pointers